# Covariant derivative identity

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I am trying to prove the following identity for contravariant vectors $X$ and $Y$ (this appears in exercise 6.7 of D'Inverno):

$\nabla_{X}(fY) = (Xf)Y + f \nabla_X Y$.

I have a way of proving it but it assumes linearity of the function $f$, whereas the proof is supposed to hold if $f$ is any smooth function. Here's my proof:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\nabla_{X}(fY) &=& X^b \nabla_b(fY^a)\\
 &=& X^b(\partial_b (fY^a) + fY^c\Gamma^{a}_{cb})\\ 
&=& X^b(\partial_bf(Y^a) + f\partial_b Y^a + fY^c \Gamma^{a}_{cb})\\
&=&(X^b \partial_b f)Y^a + X^bf(\partial_bY^a + Y^c\Gamma^{a}_{cb})\\
&=& (Xf)Y + f(X^b\nabla_bY^a)\\
&=& (Xf)Y + f \nabla_X Y
\end{eqnarray*}

Is there a better way to prove this without assuming linearity of $f$? I have searched around for a proof of this to no avail.

Comment: I think your proof is quite good.

Comment: But it appears I'm assuming linearity for f going from the first to the second line ; I'm trying to prove the identity without that assumption.

Comment: It depends on the properties that you have gave to the covariant derivative

Comment: What do you mean by assuming linearity of $f?$

Comment: I believe I was just confused: fX means the product of f with X, rather than "f with X as an argument" so my proof makes sense. I actually assumed this in the use of the product rule, but just got confused towards the end. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[your formula or at least notation is weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Vector_fields).

let me define [the covariant derivative with the parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Recovering_the_connection_from_the_parallel_transport)  $T_a^b : T_aM \to T_b M$  instead of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{cb}^a$.

for a point $p \in M$ and $v \in T_pM$ :

$$ \nabla_v Y (p) = \frac{\partial T_{p+hv}^p Y(p+hv)}{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}}= \frac{\partial T_{p+hv}^p }{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}} Y(p) + \frac{\partial Y(p+hv)}{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}}$$
so $$\begin{eqnarray}\nabla_v (f Y) (p)&=& \frac{\partial T_{p+hv}^p }{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}} (fY)(p) + \frac{\partial f(p+hv)Y(p+hv)}{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}}\\ &=& f(p) \frac{\partial T_{p+hv}^p }{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}} Y(p)  + f(p) \frac{\partial Y(p+hv)}{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}} + Y(p) \frac{\partial f(p+hv)}{\left.\partial h \right|_{h=0}}\\&=& f(p) \nabla_v Y (p) + Y(p)\partial_v f(p)\end{eqnarray}$$

and because $(\nabla_X Y)(p) = \nabla_{X(p)} Y (p)$ we get :

$$\nabla_X (fY) = f \nabla_X Y + Y\partial_X f$$

([which is what we expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Vector_fields))

Comment: Thank you. It helps to see a proof in another notation. I presume my notation is more familiar among physicists than pure mathematicians.

Comment: no it is my preferred notation, I don't think many people use it

Comment: Remember that this is differential geometry, a subject notorious for its users to more or less develop their own notations for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was thinking of the objects after $f$ as being arguments of $f$ rather than being multiplied by $f$. This was assumed in my argument, so the linearity assumption was not used.

Comment: You can include this as an edit to your post rather than an answer.

Comment: I think this does actually answer you question so it's okay to leave it as an answer. But you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: I think it does answer my question. However, my original request was an alternative proof, so I will give the accepted answer to user1952009.